# Auto-escaping an IP address in bash alias $argv

Tags: linux, sed, bash

I want to set up a bash alias to grep all logs in a directory automatically; however, to make this user-friendly, I need to escape the periods and add a whitespace boundary so grep won't match too many lines.

First I checked to be sure that I had the right syntax to escape an address...

```
[mpenning@sasmars daily]$ echo 1.1.1.1 | sed "s/\./\\\\./g"
1\.1\.1\.1
[mpenning@sasmars daily]$
```

Next I tried to escape a CLI argument... but it's not quite getting me there...

```
[mpenning@sasmars daily]$ alias tryme='echo `sed "s/$argv[1]/\\\\./g"`'
[mpenning@sasmars daily]$ tryme 1.1.1.1
```

-> Indefinite hang until I hit <kbd>cntl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>

I realize that echo isn't going to search, but this was a simple test.

What is the simplest way to escape periods in arguments to a bash alias?

Comment: Can you really use `$argv` here?

Comment: Probably not... but what should I use?

Comment: Use `grep -F` to obviate the need for `.` escaping?

Comment: The easiest way to do anything in an alias is to use a function instead.  There is no reason to ever use an alias.

Comment: @MattH, grep -F helps with periods; however, I need to replace $argv no matter what so grep doesn't match 10.1.1.10 when I search for 10.1.1.1

Comment: Or if you really want to pursue this, `tryme () { grep $(echo "$@" | sed 's%[][\.*]%\\&%g') logfile ; }`

Comment: The `-w` option helps guard against partial matches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is a function, and you can use bash's builtin replacement syntax:

```
$ function tryme() { echo "${1//./\.}"; }
$ tryme 1.1.1.1
1\.1\.1\.1
$ tryme "also. with ... spaces"
also\. with \.\.\. spaces
```

This will avoid you from forking a `sed` process.

Comment: +1. Somehow I thought that the `${parameter/.../...}` notation was a Bash v4+ feature (so, not something everyone has), but I just tried it on Bash 3.2.25 and it worked. Good to know!

Comment: Yes, together with `${parameter#…}`, `${parameter##…}`, `${parameter%…}`, … also very useful.

Answer (score 1):

According to [§6.6 "Aliases" of the *Bash Reference Manual*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Aliases):

> There is no mechanism for using arguments in the replacement text, as in `csh`. If arguments are needed, a shell function should be used (see [Shell Functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Functions)).

Also, `sed "s/$argv[1]/\\\\./g"` wouldn't really make sense anyway, if it put the argument in the sed pattern rather than in the input string.

So, you would write:

```
function tryme() {
    echo "$(echo "$1" | sed "s/\./\\\\./g")"
}
```

or, using `<<<` to pass in the input:

```
function tryme() {
    echo "$(sed "s/\./\\\\./g" <<<"$1")"
}
```